# What is special about the number $2023$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Thanks to the Pratik Matematik's new year [celebration question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qx-O1ibqpI), I just noticed today: $2023=7\times 17^2$.

I tried to prepare another question: Find all $(x,y)$ pairs of positive integer solutions for the equation
$$2^x-y^2=2023.$$

Honestly, I cheated in my question preparation. [See WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2023). I wonder if there is another solution pair. Also, if you notice "another interesting property about $2023$", you may share here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems that $x=11$ is the only solution. $2^x-2023$ is not even a perfect power for $x\le 10^5$ , unless $x=11$.

Comment: There is a question where it is asked how $2023$ can be represented and some idendtity using the digits of $2023$ is particular striking.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h2987245_fun_facts_about_2023 Consider these?

Comment: Well, "I tried to prepare a more difficult question" So the problem has no source, do I understand correctly? I would like to ask, what is the connection between the link and the question you are asking, exactly? These are $2$ different problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter: See the first answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608782/interesting-ways-to-write-2023

Comment: The number $2023$ is a number with more than one prime factor such that, if we write it as the product of powers of distinct primes, then the exponent of the largest prime is strictly greater than any other exponent. The last time that this took place was in $1948(=2^3\times3^5)$ and the next time will be in $2058(=2\times3\times7^3)$.

Comment: @lonestudent We have some social connections. Not completely lone.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant to write $1944$ rather than $1948$.

Comment: @lonestudent You knew there was a connection! If $z$ is the solution of the first question then $(26+2023z-z^2)-5^2=2023$.

Answer (score 1):

*What is special about the number $2023$?*

$2023$ is a sum of three integer cubes, so that also every prime divisor is a sum of three integer cubes. This is not the case for the preceding years. Indeed, $2020$ and $2021$ are not a sum of three integer cubes at all, and $2022=2\cdot 3\cdot 337$ has a prime factor $337$, which is not a sum of three integer cubes.

Here we use that a cube is congruent to $0,1,-1$ modulo $9$, so that integers $n\equiv \pm 4$ cannot be the sum of three integer cubes, i.e., a three term sum of $0,1,-1$ cannot be $\pm 4$ modulo $9$. In $\Bbb Z/9$ we have $2023=6=-3=-1-1-1$, so it should be possible according to "the" conjecture, that all other numbers $n\not\equiv \pm 4\bmod 9$ are the sum of three integer cubes.

For $2023=7\cdot 17\cdot 17$ we have (to give an example)
\begin{align*}
7 & = 0^3+(-1)^3+2^3,\\
17 & = 1^3+2^3+2^3,\\
2023 & = 2^3+(-9)^3+14^3.
\end{align*}

A bit more popular are the numbers $33$ and $42$, which only admit very large cubes for such a representation, e.g.,

- $33 = 8866128975287528^3 - 8778405442862239^3 -2736111468807040^3$
- $42 = 80435758145817515^3 - 80538738812075974^3 +  12602123297335631^3$

In particular the last one for $n=42$, the answer to everything, made it to several newspapers, see the reference list at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes).

Comment: "Here we use that a cube is congruent to $0,1$ modulo $9$" — Do you mean $0, \pm 1$ modulo $9$?

Comment: @Théophile Yes, thank you! There is even a [wikiproof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cube_Modulo_9).

Answer (score 1):

If we write down the odd numbers from $1$ to $2023$ in increasing order , we get the number [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000004282444883).

It apparently has no small prime factor, but as shown and approved by PARI/GP , it is composite.

My yafu-tool unfortunately cannot handle numbers of this size , so I used PARI/GP and the online magma calculator, but without success. Alpertron might be an option, I have not checked it.

Who finds prime factors ? Can we factor this number completely ? Let us see !